# linkage error upon starting webapplication on websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

While I am trying to start the my web application on websphere 8.5.5 it failed with linkage error.

But it will work 100% correctly when I restart the websphere from services (if I do stopserver then startserver it will not work)

any idea guys why stop and start does not work as restart the websphere from services ?

Comment: Classloading problems are weird like that. What would be helpful is if you post your specific error here

Comment: @kolossus I wish I could, but I don't have the log now, but I really want to know why this happened, as I believe stop and start the server should have the same effect as the restart service.

Comment: You need to provide some stacktrace with the error message, otherwise no one will be able to help you. Restart just does stop and start so it would be very strange, if one method works and the other not.